# Free PDF API in PHP to annotate

Tags: php, pdf

Can any one suggest me the **Free PDF API** in PHP to meet the following requirement.I am working on one web app. so it requires the following features. 
1) allow the PDF reader to annotate on the selected text. 
2) reply to the annotation.
3) able to remove added annotations.

is it possible to add annotation through Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/)
OR [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) Both are free. And you must code for your requirements.

Comment: thank you kannan...i could see the feature available with TCPDF. can i do the same with Javascript . is it possible to do?

Comment: Hi Indian(Me to an Indian) Glad to help you. You can use some jquery plugins. http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-print-page-options/. But they are only print pages only.